# Verifying push authentication in Okta Java SDK

Tags: java, push, okta

How can I get the answer user provides to the push notification through their phone using Java SDK? It requires transactionId in addition to other parameters used in verification of other factors as far as I understand. But where to set this?

Comment: What did you try, and where did it go wrong?

Comment: I know how to verify a factor since it's shown on documentation and reference pages. But only the push factor's verification requires an additional verification for transaction after the user sends an answer. I can see it on Okta's Rest API but I couldn't find its Java method anywhere. Perhaps it doesn't exist in SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java/issues/321

```
ExtensibleResource resource = client.instantiate(ExtensibleResource.class);
ExtensibleResource protocolNode = client.instantiate(ExtensibleResource.class);
protocolNode.put("type", "OAUTH");
resource.put("protocol", protocolNode);
ExtensibleResource result = client.http().get(pollUrl, ExtensibleResource.class);
```